# or operator in vbscript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Does vbscript support or operator?

I want to do following code in vbscript, please help me

```
if a="address1" or b = "address2"
    then Response.Redirect("www.example.com")
endif
```

Comment: VBScript is line break sensible. You must keep the "then" on the same line as the "if".

Comment: also, space between end and if ie: End if not endif

Answer (score 12):

You were really close:

```
If a = "address1" Or b = "address2" Then 
    Response.Redirect("www.example.com") 
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Use parentheses for readability ...

```
If (a = "address1") Or (b = "address2") Then 
    Response.Redirect("www.example.com") 
End If
```